# getting error when trying to connect Jenkins and Azure DevOps on same server

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I have Jenkins and Azure DevOps both installed on a private server. I'm trying to connect Jenkins to Azure using the Azure DevOps/TFS Jenkins plugin.

In Jenkins -> Configure System screen I go to the 'TFS/Team Services' section, put in my collection URL and credentials(a PAT from Azure DevOps) and click 'Test Connection'. I get the following error: " `Please sign-in at least once as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM in a web browser to enable access to the service. - Azure DevOps Server`"

Both Jenkins and Azure DevOps are on the same Windows 2016 server. How do I solve this error?

Comment: As the error indicated, did you try logging into tfs server with the account `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`? Have a try using userName and password of an user account as the credentials instead of PAT.

Comment: @Levi Lu-MSFT This is a work server and I don't have access to that type of account. I haven't tried username/password. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by using my Azure DevOps/TFS username and password. This is interesting because I was able to connect a cloud instance of Azure DevOps to a local install of Jenkins using only a PAT. I wonder if it's because the Azure DevOps I'm trying to connect to in this situation is on a private server and uses an Active Directory login. Thanks for the suggestion @Levi Lu-MSFT.